# Measuring the Size of HttpSession object

Tags: java, tomcat, httpsession

Is there a clean and easy way to measure it other than programatically measuring the size of each data type (that each object is composed of) stored in session?

Answer (score 6):

[MessAdmin](http://messadmin.sourceforge.net/) allows you to compute the HttpSession size although it is unclear on how it [calculates the size of transient objects](http://messadmin.sourceforge.net/#%5B%5BHttpSession%20size%5D%5D).

It appears that getting an approximate size of the HttpSession object is an exercise in futility in production, and one is likely to get a more accurate size for a controlled environment.

One thing to note is that size of the serialized session object is bound to inaccurate due to changes in character encoding - Strings in Java are stored in the UTF-16 format whereas the output stream could be in a different encoding. More details on why calculating the size of an object in Java is a problem, can be found in this [JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-12/02-qa-1226-sizeof.html).

Comment: I am using this in an web application with struts-2 framework  and spring 3.4 as object container, I session size always is -1 which means it can not calculate the size of objects in the session.

Comment: @Alireza Fattahi I've struggled with the same issue. And eventually I found out that you need to use MessAdmin-SizeOf plugin in addition to MessAdmin-Core and MessAdmin-AutoProb in order to get the size of session attributes. You may want to add MessAdmin-Serializable as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's a SessionSize class [here](http://javawebparts.sourceforge.net/javadocs/javawebparts/session/SessionSize.html) that has a function to return the size of an HttpSession object passed to it, a part of the [Java Web Parts](http://javawebparts.sourceforge.net/) lib.

Answer (score 1):

Session content must be Serializable. So serialize it and see the size of the resulting byte array.

It's not equal to the in-memory size, but can be used as a rough representation of it.

P.S. Note that transient fields, if any, will be excluded.

Comment: Session attributes **should** be Serializable (as in "it's a good practice to do so"); but they don't **have** to be.

Comment: Session serialization is an effective way to save memory by saving idle sessions to disk. If Erlanged has app with non-serializable session, it's the first thing to fix instead of measuring induvidual sessions' size.

Comment: Re: must/should: container MUST accept Serializable object, and MAY accept others. It MAY also throw IllegalArgumentException on any non-serializable one. I'd say Serializable is pretty much MUST, in a WE-TOLD-YOU-SO way.